# PHP - Find Missing Data In A Range

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP, and having difficulty with a query I believe should be fairly easy. I have one table with a list of names (`Names`), and another where I have these names coupled with weeks they attended a class (`Weeks`) for a 4 week course. I simply need to find the weeks they weren't present. For example:

`Names`:

```
Name
-----
Jon
Frank
```

`Weeks`:

```
Name   Week
-----  ----
Jon    1 
Jon    2
Jon    4
Frank  1
Frank  3
Frank  4
```

I am trying to write a query that tells me that John missed week 3, and Frank missed week 2. I'm at a loss as I can't seem to make this work. Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: Do you also have a list of weeks?

Comment: Can you change how you are storing your information?  And by table do you mean a database table or just a table on a page?

Comment: Christian, I could add a list of weeks if this would help. Kevin, Yes it is a database table. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Kevin, I would find it difficult to change how I'm storing the data as it would affect many other things, so I'm afraid I don't think that would be an option.

Comment: All, here is the query I started with that tells me who missed all 4 weeks (ie, if there was a Mark who missed weeks 1,2,3, & 4): $query = "SELECT Name.Name, Weeks.Name, Weeks.Week FROM Name LEFT JOIN Weeks ON (Name.Name = Weeks.Name) WHERE Weeks.Name IS NULL";                                                              I would think it would only be a matter of tweaking this to tell me who missed specific weeks, but I'm not getting anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

you could create a table containing *all* attendances (cross join) and then take the difference:

```
SELECT n.`name`, wn.`week`
FROM `names` n, `week_numbers` wn
MINUS
SELECT `name`, `week` FROM `weeks`
```

since mysql does not support `minus` directly you have to work around it by using a `JOIN`/`NOT IN`/`NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT n.`name`, wn.`week`
FROM `names` n, `week_numbers` wn
LEFT JOIN `weeks` w
ON w.`name` = n.`name` AND wn.`week` = w.`week`
WHERE w.`name` IS NULL
```

just from the top of my head, i'm sure there are solutions which perform better.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table containing all weeks for the given course:

```
create table Allweeks (Week int(11) NOT NULL);
insert into Allweeks values (1), (2), (3), (4);
```

Use this query to get all missed weeks by users:

```
SELECT Names.Name, Allweeks.Week from Names CROSS JOIN Allweeks 
LEFT JOIN Weeks on (Allweeks.Week = Weeks.Week and Names.Name = Weeks.Name) 
WHERE Weeks.Name IS NULL ORDER BY Names.Name;
```

This is quick and dirty, but should work. I'd suggest to look into topics like [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), using [primary keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_key) and [indexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index) when desinging a database.

Comment: if you downvote, please leave a comment how to improve this answer. @andrás: I think you want a `CROSS JOIN`, not an `INNER JOIN`. using primary keys is also a very valid (and good) advice. +1 from me (if you fix your inner/cross join)

Comment: Worked like a charm...! Thank you all for you time and help. Andras, I will certainly look into DB normalization, etc. Thanks again....